# given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I've registered the app in firebase console and enabled phone sign-in and added SHA1 & SHA265 from ./gradle signingreport & downloaded google-services.json

Error:[image]

Firebase Console:
[image]

Project Settings:
[image]

**app/build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}


def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("key.properties")
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
android {
    namespace "com.xxxxhore.mosaic_doctors"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    compileSdkVersion 33
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
//            storeFile file("key2.jks")
//            storePassword "keystore3"
//            keyAlias "key"
//            keyPassword "keystore3"
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(8)
    }

    android.lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
        ignoreWarnings true //false
    }

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.xxxxhore.mosaic_doctors"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

}








flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    // implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    // implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    // implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    // implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    // implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
    // implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    // implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    // implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
}
tasks.register("prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel"){}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**project/build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'

        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Verification code:**

```
Future<void> sendOtp( String phoneNo) async{
    
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: phoneNo,
    verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async{
      await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    },
    verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
      if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
        print('The provided phone number is not valid.');
      
      }else {
        print(e.code);
      
      }

      // Handle other errors
    },
    codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
      this.verificationId = verificationId;
      print("verif id : ${this.verificationId}");
    },
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
      this.verificationId = verificationId;
    },
  ) ;
  }
```

Previously I had this error:
SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Error code:39

i tried flutterfire config.
i tried answers on the web.
i tried changing gradle versions.